# Why did eclipse build me 2 identical source folders?

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday I was working on my project, and suddenly eclipse built me 2 identical source folder..
i dont know what happend. but i hope you cant help me to delete it..

[image]

Comment: Are you working with vanilla java? I mean, the ExamGenerator project is a normal project?

Comment: yes mate. just a normal console project

Comment: Then you can delete one of those 2 folders. It should work. I would recommend you to switch to Netbeans, in my personal opinion its better than eclipse and easier to work with. If you can switch, of course.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to delete one of the folders, and eclipse just deleted both of them together ..

Comment: Does it happen everytime you create a project?

Comment: no, only at this project.. also when im trying to change only one src, it changes for the second folder too

Comment: I would just create a new project and move everything to the new one

Comment: i tried to do it too, but every change im doind at the new project (just copy and paste all the classes) all the work still saved on the last project folder and not at the new one..

Comment: `src` is shown twice, first as nested project (is this what you really want? If not, delete the nested project without deleting its content) and a second time as source folder.